# How to run IN and NOT IN SPARQL statements in python rdflib to remove the intersection of two graphs

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I'm trying to use the `IN` and `NOT IN` statements (that were if I understand correctly, introduced in SPARQL 1.1) on the python implementation of SPARQL (now in [rdfextras](http://rdfextras.readthedocs.org/en/latest/?redir)) but it seems that the syntax is not recognised.

Let's consider two sets (A and B). I want to output what is in Set A, removing what is in Set B.

```
SELECT ?title WHERE {
   some logic defining ?item and ?SetB
   FILTER (?item NOT IN ?SetB)
}
```

Maybe this particular thing was added in SPARQL 1.1 and is not supported by `rdfextra`, in which case I would love to have a workaround (or how to do it without using the `NOT IN` keyword)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried a similar query and also got a parsing exception. I have gone through [rdflib's SPARQL parser](http://code.google.com/p/rdfextras/source/browse/rdfextras/sparql/parser.py) code and it doesn't seem to exist a rule to handle `IN` or `NOT IN`. I would assume that this functionality is not implemented.

Anyway, I am not sure you are using it correctly. Having a look at the `NOT IN` definition in the [SPARQL 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-not-in) ... it defines the `IN` operator to be used against a list of expressions. Therefore, you'd do:

`FILTER (?item NOT IN (?SetB))`

<strike>And I am not completely sure if you can use variables in the right-hand side because all the examples in the spec use terms.</strike> **edit**: see RobV message , it's possible to use variables in the RLH

**workaround with one query**

One possible solution, that might work for you is to use `OPTIONAL` and `bound` (both supported in rdflib). Something like ...

```
SELECT ?title WHERE {
   some logic defining ?item
   OPTIONAL {
   some logic defining ?SetB
   }
   FILTER (bound(?SetB) && ?setB != ?item)
}
```

Without knowing more about your query I cannot advice better with this case.

**workaround with two queries**

The easiest way to solve this with rdlib is to use filters and two queries, the first query retrieves all the posible values for `?SetB`. Ant in the second query you dynamically create 
a filter:

```
SELECT ?title WHERE {
   some logic defining ?item
   FILTER (?item != <setb_val1> && ?item != <setb_val2> &&
   ... && ?item != <setb_val2>)
}
```

Comment: Great that's what I was looking for.

Comment: It should be legal to use variables in the RHS of a IN/NOT IN expression, the RHS is defined to be an `ExpressionList` in the 1.1 grammar which permits any list of `Expression` productions i.e. any valid expression and thus this should include variables

Comment: good to know, thanks Rob. The examples in the spec are a bit misleading.

Answer (score 4):

Difficult to answer without specifics, but it sounds like you want `MINUS`:

```
SELECT ?title WHERE {
    ?item ... ITEM CRITERIA ...
    MINUS { ?item ... SET CRITERIA ... }
}
```

for example:

```
SELECT ?title WHERE {
    ?item ex:colour "red" .       # item is red
    MINUS { ?item ex:size "big" } # but not in set of big things
}
```

`NOT IN` is a bit misleading: as far as I can tell it operates over a list expression, not  a list you can define.

Comment: I don't think `MINUS` is implemented in RDFLIB, but nice catch.

Comment: yes, `MINUS` is a 1.1 feature and thus not implemented in rdflib. (But that's the obious solution I came too as well)